# Write to dynamic destination to cloud storage in dataflow in Python

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I was trying to read from a big file in cloud storage and shard them according to a given field.

I'm planning to Read | Map(lambda x: (x[key field], x)) | GroupByKey | Write to file with the name of the key field.

However I couldn't find a way to write dynamically to cloud storage. Is this functionality supported?

Thank you,
Yiqing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [`FileSystems` API](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/filesystems.py) to create the files.

Comment: Thank you! I was using a FileSystems.create handle inside ParDo to write the grouped the results. However it seems like that GroupByKey will wait for all the data being read in and then start the writing to a single file. So I have two followup questions: 1) Can I use wildcards using FileSystems API? 2) Is there a way so that GroupBy doesn't have to wait for all the data, otherwise there might be a memory issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

An experimental write was added to the Beam python SDK in 2.14.0, `beam.io.fileio.WriteToFiles`:

```
my_pcollection | beam.io.fileio.WriteToFiles(
      path='/my/file/path',
      destination=lambda record: 'avro' if record['type'] == 'A' else 'csv',
      sink=lambda dest: AvroSink() if dest == 'avro' else CsvSink(),
      file_naming=beam.io.fileio.destination_prefix_naming())
```

which can be used to write to different files per-record.

You can skip the `GroupByKey`, just use `destination` to decide which file each record is written to. The return value of `destination` needs to be a value that can be grouped by.

More documentation here:

https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.14.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html#dynamic-destinations

And the JIRA issue here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2857